# PHP Update Query didnt works

Tags: phpquery

I have one form text field in index.php and i fill 8080

```
http_port : <input size="5" name="http_port" value="3128">
```

and table 'squid' like this

no   | tag       |   value

1     | http_port |   3128

when i click submit button its redirect to submit.php but the table didnt update the value or still 3128.

submit.php

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
$value = $_POST['http_port'];
$query = mysql_query("update squid set http_port='$value' where '$no'=1");
echo "Update was Succesful<br>
<a href=\"index.php\">Bac</a>";
?>
```

whats wrong with my script? Thanks and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: what is $no ?? should not it be `no`

Comment: $no is column no in table 'squid' sir. i change $query = mysql_query("update squid set http_port='$value' where no = 1"); its too didnt work

Comment: have you seen my answer ??

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake in your mysql_query call, it should be:

```
$query = mysql_query("update squid set tag ='$value' where no=1");
```

I haven't coded anything in PHP for ages, but there are plenty of tutorials for such simple MySQL/PHP forms. Code I provided updates tag column, and in similar way you can update other columns...

```
$query = mysql_query("update squid set value ='$value' where no=1 and tag = 'http_port'");
```

Comment: $query = mysql_query("update squid set value ='$value' where no=1");
it works thx sir :)

Comment: It should not work properly. $value is in single quotes so will not get the value of variable $value.

Comment: Even though I havent tested this code, I think it will work fine even with single quotes, because of double quotes, like query(" '$value' ")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

index.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="submit.php" method="post">
        http_port : 
            <input size="5" name="http_port" value="3128" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

submit.php:

```
<?php
    require("conn.php");
    if(isset($_POST['http_port']))
    {
        $value = $_POST['http_port'];

        //You should sanitize data before inserting into table
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($value))));
        $no="your table field name";
        $sql = "UPDATE squid SET http_port=".$value." where ".$no."=1";
        $query = mysql_query($sql) OR die("Err:".mysql_error());
        echo "Update was Successful<br /><a href=\"index.php\">Back</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Something else";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$value is in single quotes so will not get the value of variable $value.

```
$sql = "update squid set http_port='".$value."'where no=1";
```